# How to work down a list in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have VBA code where I have a reference to a cell. Is there a possible way to work down a list of data each time the macro loops? For example, the first loop I need it to refer to cell A1, then the second loop Cell A2, and so on

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim strURL As String
Dim objelement As Object
Sub login()
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library


Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://minecraft.net/profile"

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
 Loop
IE.document.getElementById("username").Value = "DYNAMIC CELL COLUMN A"
 IE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "DYNAMIC CELL COLUMN B"

Dim htmlForm As HTMLFormElement
Set htmlForm = IE.document.getElementById("loginForm")
 htmlForm.submit



Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)

IE.navigate "https://minecraft.net/profile/password"
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
IE.document.getElementById("oldPassword").Value = "DYNAMIC CELL COLUMN B"
IE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "DYNAMIC CELL COLUMN C"
IE.document.getElementById("passwordConfirmation").Value = "DYNAMIC CELL COLUMN C"
With IE.document

Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each e In elems

    If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Submit Query") Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If

Next e


Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each e In elems

    If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Log out") Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If

Next e

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes you can - to get full answer you may wana add your code to the Question

Comment: Use nested loops. Outer loop loops over the cells to reference, inner loop loops over the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Can use a For...Each loop:

```
Sub LoopEachCellInRange()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")

    For Each MyCell In MyRange

        MyCell.Offset(, 1) = MyCell.Address

        If IsEmpty(MyCell) Then MyCell.Offset(, 2) = "It's empty"

        If MyCell.Row > 1 Then

            MyCell.Offset(, 3) = MyCell.Row + MyCell.Offset(-1).Row

            'Formula using R1C1 format.
            MyCell.Offset(, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C4:RC4)"

            'Formula using A1 format.
            MyCell.Offset(, 5).Formula = "=SUM(E1:" & MyCell.Offset(, 4).Address & ")"

        End If

    Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thought I'd add how to add formula as well - first uses R1C1 format.  `R1C4:RC4` is the same as saying row 1, column 4 to this row, column 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just whipped this up, give it a try

```
Sub loopDo()
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        'whatever you want the code to do in each cell replaces this message box
        MsgBox (ActiveCell.Value)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This could create a string of unwanted message boxes (really annoying) use `Debug.Print` to get an output instead

Comment: Indeed, that's why I added in the comment to replace that line. The messagebox section is only a reference for OP to see where they can put their own code. Since they only said 'reference cells', I've left it open for them to interpret.